# How to get the same color for status bar and toolbar with drawer above

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat

This is making me crazy. 
I want to have a navigation drawer which is covered by transparent status bar and the status bar with the same color as toolbar. Like on these two images:
[image: Same colors]
[image: Drawer]

So I set the toolbar and status bar color to the same value. That was ok and it looked as expected. Except the fact that drawer was rendered below the status bar. OK, everyone says: add the translucent attribute. So I added `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` to my theme but a weird side-effect occured - the status bar color changed to some very dark one.

[image]

Any thougts?

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = requireView(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = requireView(R.id.drawer);
    drawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(R.color.primary);
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**style.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `DrawerLayout` has been updated and those tutorials saying add a `android:windowTranslucentStatus` is out of date.

To make this work in latest support library (now 23.1.0), add the following attributes in `values-v21` (as in [CheeseSquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml)).

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

You can always find usage pattern of support library in [the CheeseSquare sample](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/), although I believe such directions should be documented offically instead of living inside blog posts and samples.